# Error Installing Android SDK Platform Tools

Tags: android

I have downloaded eclipse, the android SDK starter package, and installed the "Developer Tools." Following the guide on developer.android.com exactly. After the developer tools have installed, and eclipse restarts I get two error messages:

1: `"SDK Platform Tools component is missing!
   Please use the SDK Manager to install it."`

So, I go in eclipse under Windows > Android SDK Manager and while trying to fetch the files it brings up the sdk manager log with the following:

```
    Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml

    Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect

    Fetched Add-ons List successfully
    Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml

    Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect

Done loading packages.
```

Because of this error I cannot use the SDK Manager to install it. Any ideas on how to fix this?

2: "Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection." 
   No idea what this one means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent a few hours googling trying to find fixes but nothing seems to work, or the fixes refer to a non-existent "settings" window.

Comment: Did you try http instead of https?  http: //dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Did you install into Program Files?  Could it be you need to run the SDK manager as Admin?

Comment: I've tried both of these things.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set the SDK installation path yourself somewhere in eclipse. Look out for such problems!!

Comment: Well, even when I try to load the packages with just the android SDK, nothing with eclipse, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a proxy which is not allowing SDK manager to fetch the add-on list. You could try to put in an exception for this url and try again.

Adding an exception had worked for me earlier.